# Storing a cumulative value to a variable from within a function that's in a for loop, then recalling that variable elsewhere

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble understanding a particular concept.

The general problem is storing a cumulative value to a variable from within a function that's in a *for loop*, then recalling the variable elsewhere.

I'll explain all of the parts first:

I call to an API to get the value of a key. The call looks something like this.

```
keyName = API.key('keyName'); 
keyName.get(function(err, value) {
   console.log(value);
 });
```

However, I need to get a whole bunch of these keys, so I put the call into a *for loop*. I also want to store the cumulative value in the variable *fullString*

```
var fullString = [];

for (var i = 0; i < numberOfKeys; i++) {      
  keyName = API.key('keyName' + i);
  keyName.get(function(err, value) {
    fullString += value;

    console.log(fullString);
  });
}
```

Let's say:

```
keyName0 : 'a'
keyName1 : 'b'
keyName2 : 'c'
```

When the loop runs, I'll get this (which I understand):

```
a
ab
abc
```

The thing that I don't understand is, if I reference *fullString* outside of the function it returns *null* i.e.

```
var fullString = [];

for (var i = 0; i < numberOfKeys; i++) {      
  keyName = API.key('keyName' + i);
  keyName.get(function(err, value) {
    fullString += value;
  });
  console.log(fullString);
}
console.log(fullString);
```

Both of the above console.log's will return *null*, shouldn't they log the full value i.e. *abc*

Comment: `keyName.get(function(err, value)` is async, correct?

Comment: @DavinTryon correct `keyName.get(function(err, value)` is async.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with scoping but with asynchronicity. You are logging the value of `fullString` before this is resolved.
If you put the log call just after the `fullString += value` statement you will see that the variable is in fact equal to `abc` (on the last iteration).
However because `get()` is async `fullString` will be update after you called `console.log`.

***update***: to get the final value i suggest you read on javascript [promises](http://www.promisejs.org/).
AngularJS has a very nice implementation of it derived by Kris Kowal's Q, read [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q).

in your case it would work something like (just an idea):

```
var fullString = keyname.getAll().done(function (data) { return data; });
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. So how do I **only** get the final iteration of _fullString_ ?

Comment: Thanks very much @Joe - I'll give that a try and read up on promises, and let you know how it goes. Thanks again.

Comment: @YoDK please consider accepting the answer if the references i gave you resolve your problem.